# ResponsiveSlides Fading the pager without affecting content below and responsively?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-slides

I have taken the jQuery plugin Responsive Slides and have attempted to make my own modifications to it. Everything is going pretty well, except I'm having an issue with being able to make the pager and next/prev controls fade in when the container is hovered on.

I have managed to get the fading to work well, the only problem is that when the pager controls fade in, the content beneath it is pushed down, and then up again if I hover off the slider.

I'm not sure how to fix it, because I don't think using position absolute is going to work, as it needs to remain responsive. I get the feeling I'm going to have to make some changes to the javascript file because those parts are inserted inline via js, and that's quite a way out of my comfort zone. Any help would be massively appreciated!

The issue: http://hosting.ladesigns.co.uk/test/

This is my first time here, and if you need more information please just ask, apologies in advance if I've missed something obvious!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. :-)

Try just adding this to your CSS:

```
.centered-btns_tabs {margin-bottom: 0;}
```